# Advice on reusing images/illustrations from an AIMS paper

Tags: citations, copyright, doi

I'm working on a chemistry paper about the [Belousov-Zhabotinsky-reaction](http://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/dcdsb.2018061) (a chemical oscillator).

On of my sources is [this paper from the AIMS](http://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/dcdsb.2018061). In the paper the authors have a few figures, especially figure 2 (you can view it on the website). If permitted by the copyright, I would like to include the figure.

I've no idea how the copyright is regulated with such papers. The AIMS website provides even an option to download the full-size figure.

What is the copyright for DOI-papers (by the AIMS)? And how can I determine such a thing the next time (if it has an DOI)?

For this specific case, is it allowed to include the figure, on the condition of correct reference?

Comment: Did you consider asking the author directly?

Comment: One problem with images is that they can be considered a "complete work" in themselves, even when part of a larger work. (One picture is worth a thousand words.) So "fair use" can get more complicated. So, yes, ask the authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the authors will have assigned all copyright for figures to the journal upon submission/publication. I'm not familiar with the journal in question but it does not look to be any different from any I've ever seen (it has a title, volume, page number etc so is 'normally' citeable). If you wish to reproduce figures from any journal or other source then you need to contact the publisher. This is usually just a formality.

In this case the contact page for the AIMS (https://www.aimsciences.org/common_news/column/contact) indicates you should get in touch with the Editorial Manager - editorial@aimsciences.org "Regarding the book/journal editorial process, book orders, Printed version claims, *copyrights*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks for researching that @jovisg!